# Nan object in Python String list

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, nan

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'....movie_metadata.csv')
director = df.director_name.tolist() #I kept director names to list
movie = df.movie_title.tolist()
```

But problem is director list has some nan values. When i write the code belove;

```
directorName = input("Please enter director: ")
i = 0
while(i < 5043):
 if "nan" != director[i]:
    if directorName.__eq__(director[i]):
       print (director[i], movie[i])
i = i + 1
```

But the output is

> Sam Raimi The Quick and the Dead 
>   nan Friday Night Lights 
>   Sam Raimi Drag Me to Hell 
>   nan The Family 
>   nan Entourage 
>   nan Trapped 
>   nan 12 Monkeys 
>   nan Limitless 
>   nan The Honeymooners  
>   ...

and so on. I do not want to print nan values and nan values's movies. How can i edit this code?

Comment: i forgot to write movie = df.movie_title.tolist() above sorry

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if not math.isnan(director[i]):
# your code
```